# SQL averaging over column values for an id in the table, grouped by values in the same column for a different id in the table

Tags: sqlite, subquery

I have searched SO but can't find a case that matches mine. This is because the same column in my table needs to be used for Averaging and Grouping By, however the catch is that the id is different when implementing each function. Let me explain:
This is my 'Answers' table:

[image]

Now Question with ID 1 is "What is your age" and Question ID 2 is "What is your gender". I found the top 7 genders, these are : 'Male', 'Female', 'male', 'female', '-1', 'Nonbinary', 'non-binary'

AnswerText contains the answers for each question. I want to get the Average age for each gender category in the list.
I have done this:

```
SELECT AVG(AnswerText), Gender
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT AnswerText as Gender
      FROM Answer
      WHERE Answer.QuestionID = 2 
      AND Gender IN ('Male', 'Female', 'male', 'female', '-1', 'Nonbinary', 'non- 
     binary')
    )
    WHERE Answer.QuestionID = 1
    GROUP BY Gender
```

This is throwing error 'no such column: AnswerText'
I am using SQLlite, how do I achieve this? I can provide the table if required
Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you're using SQLite, why is MySQL tagged?

Comment: MySQL and SQLite are two totally different RDBMSs, with different functionality and syntax. It's clear you're not using both of them. Please [edit] your post and remove the one that does not apply. Tag spamming is inappropriate - tags have relevance and meaning here, and shouldn't be abused. Mis-tagging also risks wasting both your time and hours when someone takes the time to write an answer, only to find out it won't work in the RDBMS you're actually using. You're asking us to donate time to help you - don't make it more difficult by failing to provide the proper details.

Comment: Ok so,
1) It is obvious I am a beginner
2) Won't the Sqllite and mysql solution be same for this problem?
I have removed it regardless

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT AVG(AnswerText), Gender
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT AnswerText as Gender  //Try to remove as Gender, the alias is not necesary
      FROM Answer
      WHERE Answer.QuestionID = 2 
      AND Gender IN ('Male', 'Female', 'male', 'female', '-1', 'Nonbinary', 'non- 
     binary')  // remove the AND statement. I think is redundant
    )
    WHERE Answer.QuestionID = 1
    GROUP BY Gender // This should group by all different genders or you can group then by later.
```

This is just based from a conceptual point of view. I don't have the software available to help more.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: How does this help? This is exactly the code that I wrote

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).